# Detecting the timeframe of accelerometer detected motion

Tags: iphone, uiaccelerometer

How does one detect the amount of time the device has detected motion on the accelerometer?

If I wanted to detect continuous motion detection on the device such as 10 seconds of motion. How is this done? When I use the accelerometer delegate method, it keeps being called and is difficult to handle the time calculation.

Comment: The accelerometer cannot detect motion anyway. Only acceleration (= change of motion).

Comment: 10 seconds of continuous accelerometer data. I would like to try an trigger certain actions once e.g. the device has been moved around/shaken etc for n seconds

Answer (score 0):

As commented, accelerometer  delivers acceleration values and not speed -  so you will have to integrate  over incoming values.  Bu bevare of:
   - earth gravity is always there 
   - there is a lot of noise (accelerometer chips built in phones are really cheap, crappy and
sell for 10$  a bucket)